# Certbot www and non-www with --non-interactive = vhost ambiguity

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to generate a certificate for single domain but for both www and non-www.

This is how I run it now:

```
certbot --apache -n -d domain.tld -d www.domain.tld --agree-tos --email mail@domain.com --redirect
```

But I'm getting the following:

> Encountered vhost ambiguity but unable to ask for user guidance in
>   non-interactive mode. Currently Certbot needs each vhost to be in its
>   own conf file, and may need vhosts to be explicitly labelled with
>   ServerName or ServerAlias directories.

So I have to run it without the -n(--non-interactive) and select the proper vhost file.

Is there any way I can generate the certificate for www and non-www without any prompts?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities that could cause this error message. It indicates that there is something wrong with your vhost configuration.
But to summarize the most prominent causes:

- You have multiple `<VirtualHost >` in a single `.conf` file
- You have multiple `.conf` files, e.g. for port 80 and 443, which do not have exactly the same `ServerName` and/or `ServerAlias` attributes
- You didn't specify any `ServerName` at all in the `.conf` file
- `domain.tld` and/or `www.domain.tld` are not specified in your `.conf` files

Furthermore, I recommend you to run certbot with the `--dry-run` option for debugging. Additionally, for automatic renewal in cron there is `/etc/certbot-auto renew`
So, you could then try `/etc/certbot-auto renew --dry-run` to just take all domains specified in the config files.
Reminder: Please, don't forget to also restart or reload apache with `service apache2 restart` or similar after each change in the vhost config

Answer (score 0):

certbot needs you to properly configure your virtual hosts. You need to edit apache2 config file so that `www.domain.com` is an alias for `domain.com`

[you need to edit the appropriate config files according to your server setup]

for example my server is like so

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
    ErrorLog /error.log
    CustomLog /access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Then run certbot again

```
sudo certbot  --noninteractive --agree-tos  --no-eff-email  --cert-name domain.com --apache --no-redirect  -d domain.com -d www.domain.com -m siteadminsemail@gmail.com
```

I hope it helps someone, it nagged me for 2 days and i even got temporarily banned by letsencrypt for trying to use certbot too many times :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can generate the certificate for www and non-www without any prompts?

No, currently there is [not](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/encountered-vhost-ambiguity/92519/3). If you have complex vhosts, I wouldn't trust certbot to manage them correctly. This just feels unreliable, and it turns out, at least at current it is unreliable in practice.

About the only thing certbot's apache module can do to you vhosts reliably is install a default SSL vhost on a fresh install in the *single* `--domain` case. For anything else use `certonly` option, then drop in your vhosts linking to the generated certs, which is easy. The path to the cert can be reliably determined by the value of the *first* domain parameter or as specified by `--cert-name` argument. So:

```
certbot certonly --apache -n --domains domain.tld,www.domain.tld --agree-tos --email mail@domain.com
```

Then drop in a vhost linking to the certs path. Example default SSL vhost `000-default-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    # LogLevel info ssl:warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    # ServerName not required for default.
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Then reload:

```
a2ensite 000-default-ssl.conf
service apache2 reload
```